# ruby string convert ascii to unicode

Tags: ruby, unicode, character-encoding

I have a string which has ascii special characters and i want to convert those to respective unicode characters. For example below is the string

```
A “razor” is a rule of thumb that simplifies decision..  \nWe’re in a post-content age.  In the past,\nhealthier, wealthier life:  • Toxic relationships • Comparisons • Inactivity • Complaints • Instant gratification • Overthinking • Crazy “what if” fears
```

Expect output

```
A "razor" is a rule of thumb that simplifies decision..  \nWe're in a post-content age.  In the past,\nhealthier, wealthier life:  • Toxic relationships • Comparisons • Inactivity • Complaints • Instant gratification • Overthinking • Crazy "what if" fears
```

The best result I could get is using [unidecode](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/unidecode/1.0.0/frames#label-unidecode) gem. Which converted the above string to this

```
"A \"razor\" is a rule of thumb that simplifies decision..\nWe're in a post-content age.  In the past,\nhealthier, wealthier life:  * Toxic relationships * Comparisons * Inactivity * Complaints * Instant gratification * Overthinking * Crazy \"what if\" fears "
```

The problem with the approach is unidecode to_ascii method  will convert the character if the string is in another language.

Comment: What encoding is your source string in? And why do you want to convert `“` to `"` instead of keeping it? Do you think it’s not available in Unicode? It almost sounds as if you want to convert from Unicode to ASCII. Please clarify.

Comment: ASCII is a proper subset of Unicode: Every character that exists in ASCII also exists in Unicode, and every character that exists in ASCII has the exact same code in ASCII and Unicode. Therefore, "convert ASCII to Unicode" is simply a NO-OP. Any ASCII string *is already a Unicode string with the exact same characters*.

Comment: The characters you've mentioned (`” `, `’`, `•`, etc.) aren't ASCII characters. Those characters exist in other character sets like Windows-1252 (sometimes erroneously called "extended ASCII," ISO-8859-1 (a.k.a. Latin-1) and Unicode encodings like UTF-8, but not ASCII. It doesn't seem like you want to convert a string from ASCII to Unicode; rather, it looks like you're trying to replace *non-ASCII* characters with some equivalent. In that case, do you have a list of the characters you want to replace, and what you want to replace them with?

Comment: @JordanRunning You are right. I want to replace non-ascii characters with some equivalent. I don't have a list. I getting this data from 3rd party API. Which I'm displaying.

Comment: @Stefan I'm sending this text data to kindle these characters are breaking, for example, **"** is showing as   **å€œ**

Comment: @shiva that seems to be an encoding issue, but I don't think ASCII will help here. How do you send your text data to kindle? What kind of data / file is that? Can you show some code or give more context?

Answer (score 0):

So what you are asking about is not ascii but ASNI also known as windows-1252, I would recommend you take a look at the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) wiki as it has a table with the Unicode code points marked on the table. Essentually there is no easy and quick way to convert from ansi to unicode and the way it was done with the table in that wiki page is the same glyph was found in unicode and substituted in.

One thing about ansi, asci, and unicode is the first 128 characters are all the same between them.

personally I would just make a look up table and also how ruby seems to handle unicode character strings is using the following: "\u<code point in hex>" where you replace the <code point in hex> with the hexadecimal value of the code point so for say the bullet point: "•" would be converted to: "\u2022" if you need to look up unicode code points I recommend: [unicodeplus.com](https://unicodeplus.com) as it even gives you the escape sequence used for each codepoint for a few different programming languages.

Comment: _"there is no easy and quick way to convert from ansi to unicode"_ – so Ruby’s `String#encode` doesn’t work here?

Comment: @stefan I tried str.encode it returned the same string.
```
str.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: @shiva `Encoding:UTF-8` means that your string _is_ already UTF-8 encoded. What are you trying to do? What is the actual problem here, i.e. why do you have to convert those quotation marks in the first place?